# compress.zlib adding symbols to the end of xml string

Tags: php, javascript, gzip

I wrote the following php code to:

1. download an xml.gz file 

2. decompress the file and get the contents as a string

3. save it as an xml file.

```
$data = file_get_contents('compress.zlib://'.$url);
file_put_contents($name, $data);
echo file_get_contents($name);
```

The code works absolutely fine except for one irritating bug.
The XML file it generates (after decompressing), has several symbols attached to the end of it such as these:

```
    qD�_}7
```

I need to fix this bug because when I parse this XML string in javascript to convert into an XML object, it gives the following error - "Invalid XML"

Please suggest corrections or alternative solutions to the problem.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with source file xml.gz. I checked it by manually downloading and extracting. It is a properly formed XML file.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the xml.gz file?